# What is different BluetoothManager#getAdapter() and BluetoothAdapter#getDefaultAdapter()?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implement a BluetoothLeScan.

But I don't know what is different `BluetoothManager#getAdapter()` and `BluetoothAdapter#getDefaultAdapter()`.

I found out `BluetoothManager#getAdapter()` invokes `BluetoothAdapter#getDefaultAdapter()`.

But `BluetoothManager#getAdapter()` injects `context` into `BluetoothAdapter` instance.

What difference does this make?

If you look at the developer documents, it says

> To get a `BluetoothAdapter` representing the local Bluetooth adapter, call the `BluetoothManager#getAdapter` function on `BluetoothManager`. On JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and below you will need to use the static `getDefaultAdapter()` method instead."

But They are using both methods in the example.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#Profiles

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#setup

Bluetooth -> use `BluetoothAdapter#getDefaultAdapter()` 
Bluetooth Low Energy -> use `BluetoothManager#getAdapter()`

Is that right??

Please let me know....